# Typo in close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

Currently, one of the off-topic close reasons reads:

> Questions about **playing video games** and **developing video game** are off-topic here, but may be on-topic on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) and the [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/about), respectively.

Shouldn't that be changed to *developing video game**s***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be plural. Good eye.

Changing a custom close reason in the system is (deliberately) a bit more difficult than just a simple edit so this won't be changed righty away, but it's now on the ToDo list. Thanks!